# hasMany, belongsTo, belongsToMany parameters with custom names?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have these db tables:

```
author (atr_id pk)                              // model : Author
category (ctg_id pk)                            // model : Category
post (pst_id pk, pst_atr_id fk)                 // model : Post
post_categories (pct_pst_id fk, pct_ctg_id fk)  // pivot : PostCategories
```

how to define the hasMany, belongsTo, belongsToMany parameters with custom names?

Model : Author

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', ?, ?);
}
```

Model : Post

```
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', ?, ?);
}

public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', ?, ?, ?);
}
```

Model : Category

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', ?, ?, ?);
}
```

Comment: show the database structure of these tables?

Comment: You mean custom foreign keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Author   : $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'pst_atr_id', 'atr_id');

Post     : $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'pst_atr_id', 'atr_id');

Post     : $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories', 'pct_pst_id', 'pct_ctg_id');

Category : $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_categories', 'pct_ctg_id' 'pct_pst_id');
```

Answer (score 4):

**Model : Author**

```
<?php

public function getPosts(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Post','pst_atr_id');// author table's foreign key in Post table.
}
```

**Model : Post**

```
<?php

 public function getAuthor(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Author','pst_atr_id','atr_id'); // first is foreign key of author table in this current table and second is primary key name of author table.
 }

 public function getCategories(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','post_categories','pct_pst_id ','pct_ctg_id'); /* 'post_categories' is the pivot table. Rest 2 parameters- first is foreign key present in post_categories of the current model, second is foreign key present in post_categories of the model we are relating with*/
 }
```

**Model : Category**

```
<?php

 public function getPosts(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post','post_categories ','pct_ctg_id','pct_pst_id');

    /* 'post_categories' is the pivot table. Rest 2 parameters- first is foreign key present in post_categories of the current model, second is foreign key present in post_categories 
     of the model we are relating with*/
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Model : Author

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'pst_id', 'atr_id');
}
```

Model : Post

```
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'pst_atr_id', 'pst_id');
}

public function getCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories', 'pct_pst_id', 'pct_ctg_id');
}
```

Model : Category

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_categories', 'pct_ctg_id', 'pct_pst_id');
}
```